# Log4j: values not shown on console

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I try to use Log4j, but it does not show values of variables on console output

```
 LOG.info("Id:", idValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't you missing the placeholder for the variable?

```
LOG.info("Id: {}", idValue);
```

Note that this will only work in Log4j2 though.